# Pendulum collision problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision

> 2 steel balls are hung on threads in a way that they are touching each other and their centers of gravity are $l = 1 ,5 \  \mathrm{meters}$ below the hang points, threads are vertical. Masses of the steel balls are $m_1 = 1,6 \rm \ kg$ and $m_2 = 0,4 \rm \  kg$. The ball of a lower mass is hung horizontally by $90°$ and released, making a perfectly elastic collision with the heavier ball.
>
> Calculate:
>
> 1. The heights of the balls $h_1$ and $h_2$ after the collision
> 2. A ratio between masses, where the heights the balls reach after the collision are equal.

I managed to calculate $(1)$ using lots of information, but have no idea how to solve $(2)$. The solution to $(1)$ is welcome as well for assurance, because I may have made a mistake or two there.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: HINT:  If the heights the balls reach after the collision are equal, that means that their velocities immediately after the collision must have been equal in magnitude and opposite in direction.

Comment: Another hint: try using the center of mass reference frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your head around what statement "heights the balls reach after the collision are equal." is equivalent to. Since the gravitational acceleration is the same regardless of mass, the height balls reach after the collision must only be dependent on the velocity right after the collision. This means the balls' speed must be equal, and the direction opposite.

Relative velocity stays the same after elastic collisions. Let the speed of the balls right after the collision be $v$, then $m_2$'s velocity right before the collsion must be $2v$. Finally, let $m_1=km_2$ and use conservation of momentum to solve for $k$.

$2m_2v=km_2v-m_2v$

$k=3$

Therefore, the larger mass must be three times heavier than the lesser for the situation in the problem to happen.